# How to import tensorflow eminist letters dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to import tensorflow eminist letters category datasets. [as shown in this dataset catalog](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/emnist#emnistletters)
but I don't see any examples showing how to import these dataset anywhere in the documentation.
How can I import eminist dataset from tensorflow datasets library ?
I know there's other way to get the dataset like extra_keras_datasets package like below code

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = emnist.load_data(type='letters')
```

but I want to import from tensorflow only.

Any help on how to import this will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#load_a_dataset

Comment: Yea but there's no mention of eminist letters related

Answer (score 0):

You could import emnist dataset like below as mentioned in above [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#load_a_dataset)

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('emnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
assert isinstance(ds, tf.data.Dataset)
print(ds)
```